# Help constructing the following formal definitions

Tags: real-analysis

For a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be able to write down the formal definition in symbols of each of the following.

• it converges to real number $L$

• it converges

• it diverges

• it diverges to $\infty$

Here is what I have. My problem is I don't know what the difference is between the formal definition of converges to real number $L$ and converges.

Converges to real number $L$:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \; \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \; \text{such that} \; \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \; n \geq N \implies |x_n - L| < \epsilon$$

Converges:

$$\exists L \;  \forall \epsilon > 0, \; \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \; \text{such that} \; \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \; n \geq N \implies |x_n - L| < \epsilon$$

Diverges:

$$\exists \epsilon > 0 \; \text{such that} \; \forall N \in \mathbb{N}, \; \exists n \in N \; \text{such that} \; n \geq N \; \text{and} \; |x_n - L| > \epsilon$$

Comment: `My problem is I don't know what the difference is between the formal definition of converges to real number L and converges` This is a quite technical distinction, and it depends on how your book defines "*converges*" vs. "*limit*" (or "*converges to*"). You'll need to add more context (such as the precise book definitions) for any meaningful answer to be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give the general definitions and leave you to do the symbolic ones. When it says "converges to a real number $L$", I assume that means that the number $L$ is fixed from the start. Your symbolic rendition is right. For general convergence, I would say that **there exists an** $L$ such that the definition for convergence to $L$ holds, so you should change your second equation.

For diverges, your symbolic definition assumes that you already have a specific $L$ in mind, which is bad, because as you have it written, you are saying that the sequence **does not converge to** $L$, which is not the same as diverges (it could converge to a different number, say $L'$, and the definition of diverge as you have written would still be satisfied).

Diverges to $\infty$ is a separate case. We say that a sequence diverges to infinity if the values of sequence become arbitrarily large (i.e. greater than any fixed positive value $M$). More specifically, for any value $M > 0$, then past a certain $N$ (dependent on $M$ but fixed), we have $a_n > M$ for $n > M$. I've given many hints, see if you can construct the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the definition of convergence found in the book by Vladimir A. Zorich:

[image]

Hence, if there exists a limit $L$, the sequence is said to be convergent.

Comment: One of the definitions listed was Cauchy sequence that you gave, so I am thinking the plain convergence definition may be different.